# Changing caption sizes of subfigures

Tags: subfloats

I would like to know how I can change the fontsize of the captions associated with my subfigures. I want the caption of the subfigures to be smaller than that of the figure.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/B2.png}
     \caption{Bandstructuur $2$ natrium atomen.}
     \label{fig:B2}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/B3.png}
     \caption{Bandstructuur $3$ natrium atomen.}
     \label{fig:B3}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/BN.png}
     \caption[10pt]{Bandstructuur $N_A$ natrium atomen in kristalstructuur.}
     \label{fig:BN}
 \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Vorming bandstructuur van natrium (Na) atomen. Breedte van banden neemt toe naarmate de hoeveelheid atomen toeneemt zodat er uiteindelijk een bandstructuur ontstaat.}
    \label{fig:B23N}
\end{figure}
```

[image]